# When to resend lost ACK for Sliding Window with Selective Repeat ARQ

Tags: c, networking, sliding-window

As you can probably tell, I'm a bit confused on sliding window with a selective repeat ARQ implementation. If the receiver sends an ACK for a packet, and the ACK gets lost, what does the sender do? Does the sender continue on till the data file with no ACK becomes the bottom of the window and then handle it? Or does the sender wait until the ACK is recieved and then continues?

Answer (score 0):

The server will continue to send data packets until it's window fills up. The receiver will always send a cumulative ACK of the data it has received. This just means that when the receiver sends an ack, it always sends the lowest sequence number it has not received. So if the ack for packet 1 is lost, the server will still send packet 2, the client will ack packet 2 indicating that it is ready to receive packet 3, and the server will update its window with this information upon receiving this ack.

Comment: Uhh... I don't think selective repeat uses cumulative acks. That sounds like Go-Back-N. Selective repeat uses selective... acks.